# Using MAMP and mysql on Terminal application (macintosh)?

Tags: terminal, remote, database, mamp

Looking link to learn about using mysql Terminal commands. 
I have MAMP (LAMP for macintosh) installed in my computer. I'm trying to connect to a remote mysql database using Terminal application on my computer but I get an error message.

**What I do is:**

1. Open Terminal app
2. Go to mysql installation folder with this line: `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql`.
3. Then I try to connect to remote database with this line: `mysql -h 81.238.5.98 -u user_name -p database_name`

But I get this error message:

> 'ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `-h 81.238.5.98 -u user_name -p database_name' at line 1`

Message says I have a error in my SQL syntax but I see no errors in it. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 3 isn't a command you submit in the MySQL console, but is a `mysql` program call with parameters. After step 2, you're already connected to your local/default instance.

Replace steps 2 and 3 with

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -h 81.238.5.98 -u user_name -p database_name
```